# Referencing cordova.js on html pages

Tags: html, cordova

I have a multipage html5 app using PhoneGap.  I was told to only reference cordova.js on the index.html page (the first html file that is loaded) however, if I try using the device camera on any page other than index.html, it won't work unless I also reference cordova.js on that html page.

Can someone clarify whether it is ok to reference cordova.js on all the html pages of my html5 app?

The reason I'm concerned about referencing it more than once, is if I do, then I get errors on firebug about referencing it more than once and although it doesn't affect the app at all, I'm avoiding doing so.

Comment: You should consider reformatting your application to a single html page format. This will cut down on a lot of issues.

Comment: Does it matter if I don't?  It will take a lot of time to do this

Comment: It will most likely affect the performance of the application, but it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any page that uses Cordova must include the cordova-*.js file for the associated Cordova version and platform.

Refer [**Include Cordova**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html) section in above Phonegap Document.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference cordova.js on very page, It's part of the cordova framework that works in pair with native code for the devices.